# Showing data using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, json, ios6

i am getting the JSON object from https://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json

So, my code is the next:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    students = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
     for(NSDictionary *item in students) {
        NSLog(@"Message: %@", [item objectForKey:@"message"]);
     }
}
```

So, i get the next error:

```
2013-01-23 21:42:02.672 students[94907:11603] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7471580
2013-01-23 21:42:02.681 students[94907:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7471580'
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is creating *item as an NSString. Instead of NSLog(...[item objectForKey:@"message"], try `NSLog(@"%@", item);` to see what it is. Maybe it's already the message you want

Comment: Yes, i have tried that and i can see "errors" , but then i want to show every field as message for example.

Answer (score 0):

That means that you are calling objectForKey: out of a nil object, you should try the following to download the data into a string and then pass that string into the NSJSONSerializer, the iterate

```
NSMutableString *responseData = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
        NSLog(@"we got a response ");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
        NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [responseData appendString:response];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *students = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:[responseData UTF8String]
                                                                                    length:[responseData lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:nil];
    for(NSDictionary *item in students) {
        NSLog(@"Message: %@", [item objectForKey:@"message"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope this will help you..

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

     mData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
     [mData appendData:data];
}



-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

      NSDictionary *students = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: mData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

     for(NSDictionary *item in students) {
            NSLog(@"Message: %@", item);
        }
     NSLog(@"NSDictionary: %@", students);
 }
```